# *ngIf depending on the visibility of another div - Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to display dynamically some images depending on the visibility of the other one. I have tried the following code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let badge of user.progress.unlockedBadges">
      <img id="{{i}}_unlockedImage" *ngIf="badge == achievement.payload.doc.id"
        src="../../../assets/icons/unlocked_link.png" height="48" width="48">
    </div>
    <img *ngIf="document.getElementById({{i}}+'_unlockedImage')" src="../../../assets/icons/locked_link.png"
      height="48" width="48">
```

but it does not work. Is it possible to do it somehow using just HTML? Regards.

Comment: why are you adding JS code in `*ngIf` condition?, What you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Just use the same *ngIf that you used for the other element. Why complicate?

Comment: If I use the previous if, it will display several images (Im using an ng for the inside of another ngfor)

Answer (score 1):

Adding pure JavaScript to the angular template will not work... specifically this:

```
*ngIf="document.getElementById({{i}}+'_unlockedImage')"
```

the variable must be in the angular component context for this to work.

in your component you could create a function

```
showLock() {
 return this.user.progress.unlockedBadges.filter(badge => badge === this.achievement.payload.doc.id).length === 0;
}
```

and change your view with

```
<img *ngIf="showLock()" src="../../../assets/icons/locked_link.png"
      height="48" width="48">
```

Comment: Good. Just wanted to know if by pure HTML was possible

Comment: using functions in the template is not a good practice, it will work on every change